# How to add an ear to WAS 8.5 in RAD 8.5?

Tags: rad

I have four projects in my RAD 8.5 work space which imported from a piff file :

- A java project
- An ejb project
- A JPA project
- An EJB project

They are deployed through an ear called `prj.ear`, which also i imported from the piff zip.

I have to deploy them in WAS 8.5 . But when i try to add that ear in my WAS 8.5 , I get this prompt `there are no resources that can be added or removed from the server`. I have no idea how to solve this .. Any suggestions will be welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to my vexing problem. The reason , it was not working is that , the web project first needs to be added to the ear, which is done following the steps below :

`EAR > right-click > Properties > Project References`.

And voila, now when you try to add or remove your project ear, it will start working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for deployment descriptor of your parent as well as subproject ear, war, jar files, application.xml and web.xml.
Server is failing to search them and thats why no resource.